# Police Clearance certificate for Tier 2 validity

Tags: united-kingdom

1. My police clearance certificate from India was issued on 29th Jan, 2017.
2. Left for United Kingdom on 30th Jan, 2017 for three and half month.
3. Back in India for 17 days in total before I submit an application for Tier 2 (General) visa.

Does the PCC issued before I left for UK is still valid to apply for Visa or do i need to get a new one?

Comment: Is a Police Certificate required to extend a Tier 2 Visa?

Answer (score 1):

According the UK's National Police Chiefs' Council notes for applicants wishing to obtain a Police Certificate for immigration purposes:

> [**How long is my Police Certificate valid for?**](https://www.acro.police.uk/Police_Certificates_FAQs.aspx#How_long_is_my_Police_Certificate_valid_for?)
>
> There is no set period of time for which the Police Certificate is considered to be valid. The Police Certificate is only truly accurate on the date of issue. Embassies, high commissions, consulates or other authorities will usually require you to produce a Police Certificate which has been issued less than six (6) months before your visa interview.

Comment: Surely this is talking about UK issued police certificates, and their validity in apply for foreign visas. Whereas the question is about the validity in a foreign issued police certificate in applying for a UK visa.

Comment: @MJeffryes Yes, you're right. Exploring the linked page in Giorgio's answer reveals the Q-and-A is about police certificates obtained in the UK to be submitted to countries other than the UK. The title wording from the linked page should instead be "...a Police Certificate for *emigration* purposes."

Answer (score 1):

From the Home Office guidance on the Criminal Record Certificate requirement https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1042475/Criminal_record_certificate.pdf#page10

Validity of certificates

A certificate will normally be considered valid in the following circumstances:

• for the applicant’s latest country of residence, where it is issued no earlier than 6 months before the date of application

• for other countries where the applicant was present, where it is issued within the last 6 months before their last period of stay ended (this can be any date)